# How to get window.varName from a remote site

Tags: php, javascript, variables, window

Overview: I'm trying to add an EventBrite event using the EventBrite API with nothing but the URL as an input.

For example, a user inputs [the url] and I should be able to pull the "eid" from [the url].

I know that the source of http://pitchevent-startups.eventbrite.com/ does this:
[script]
... 
window.eid = "123456";
...
[/script]
 and I want to retrieve this  "123456" value for my own purposes (adding the event to a list.)

How can I access this? Javascript preferred, but php will be OK too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PHP to get the `eid`, like this:

```
<?php
$url='http://pitchevent-startups.eventbrite.com/';
if (preg_match('/window\.eid\s*=\s*\"(\d*)\";/',file_get_contents($url),$match)){
    echo "eid: ".$match[1];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, and is way more elegant than a solution I hacked together...lol. Still learning regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can't; cross-host requests are disallowed by browsers for security reasons.

Comment: Not a problem. If you feel that this answer is appropriate for you, you may accept it if you wish with the check mark.